# how to use gradle for muliplatform

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project on Java 11 where I'm using Gradle.
The issue I met today - multiplatform supporting on Gradle.
I have standalone *.jar and *.dll for windows and *.jar and *.so for *nix dependency.

Who can help, is there a way to using both pairs (*.jar and executable files) at the same Gradle and depending on the platform automatically use *.jar for Windows on Win machine and *.jar for Linux un *.nix machines?

PS. The classes for both jars are the same, the differences are in executable files only.